# Design pattern for Filtering a custom datastructure

Tags: java, design-patterns, collections

I have been given the below data structure and now I need to apply rules to filter the given cart. An example would be to filter out all items that are listed by user bob and with payment method credit card. The rule depends on case to case basis.

All these below are complex types in my request and response with concrete implementation without implementing an interface.

What will be the best design pattern to separate out my data structure and rules that are applied over it. Will Decorator pattern help? Your suggestions are welcome.

```
   public class PaymentType {
        private String paymentType;
    }

    public class Items {
        private Integer itemId;
        private String category;
        private List<PaymentType> paymentOptions;
    }

    public class Group {
        private Integer sellerId;
        private List<Items> itemList;
    }

    public class Cart {
        private Integer cardId;
        private List<Group> group;
    }
```

Comment: [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) can be used to make a chain of filters. Also (this is about the implementation though), I would make a "view" of the given cart that offers an iterator over the groups and items inside each group, depending on the filtering rules applied.

Comment: To clarify: you want to get from cart all items which belong to group with some sellerId AND have some paymentType listed in paymentOptions?

Comment: yeah, one typical example of rule posted over the cart. And all possible rules that can be formed.

Answer (score 0):

1. If for every PaymentType, you need to execute some different kind of operations , then you can try STATE PATTERN and delegate your request.
2. DECORATOR PATTERN is used to add extra responsibility during runtime, so I actually did not find that kind of scenario , may be I am missing somewhere some point.

Further Items , Group can be sub divided and there is a possibility of DECORATOR PATTERN.

If number of items are Fixed , then COMMAND PATTERN can be used , and UNDO scenario will even helpful for discard/accept item to/from CART